# Change in JS file not reflected in Magento 2 frontend

Tags: magento2

I've changed a JavaScript file in Magento but changes are not reflected. I also cleared the cache but nothing changed.

So if anyone know why please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 2):

Css and js files are stored in pub/static/areaname(frontend)/thememodule/theme folder.

you have to manually delete the respective js/css to reflect your changes.

Or you can run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable developer mode: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer.
2. Clean pub/static/frontend directory.
3. Run php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy (This command creates 'symlinks' for less, js files).
4. Clean cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

-f is for forcefully deployment, if it does not auto deploy.